# Using instance variables in included modules

Tags: ruby

I have `ClassA` that includes several modules

```
class ClassA
  include Module1
  include Module2      

  def initialize()
    @some_var = ...
  end

end
```

Included modules have methods that use instance variable `@some_var`

```
module Module1
  def method1
    @some_var.a()
  end
end

module Module2
  def method2
    @some_var.b()
  end
end
```

The code below works fine and is correct

```
obj = ClassA.new
obj.method1
obj.method2
```

But I don't know if it is correct to use an instance variable in included modules. Maybe I need to implement another architecture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use methods. Not only do they work as expected, this is also a proper OO technique. You're not supposed to intrude in another object's internals.

```
require 'ostruct' # for OpenStruct

module Module1
  def method1
    some_var.a
  end
end

class ClassA
  include Module1

  def initialize()
    @some_var = OpenStruct.new(a: 1, b: 2) # construct some object with some methods
  end

  attr_reader :some_var
end

obj = ClassA.new
obj.method1 # => 1
```

Comment: Thanks! Using attr_reader is the more right way as for me. The second example is very ugly:)

Comment: I agree with your answer, but if you _are_ going to use instance variables, I don't see how `instance_variable_get` has any advantage over just using the instance variable normally.

Comment: @Max: right. I thought for a second that ivars didn't work. I re-checked and they actually work. Therefore I have removed the second part of the answer.